# On Dini derivative vanishing at all but countably many points implying constant function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, monotone-functions

In Berberian's *Fundamentals of Real Analysis* [1], there is the following result:

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$, and $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ a function satisfying the following conditions:

(i) If $x\in[a,b)$, then $$f(x)\leq\liminf_{t\to x^+}f(t).$$
(ii) If $x\in(a,b]$, then $$\limsup_{t\to x^-}f(t)\leq f(x).$$
Let $\mathscr{D}$ by any of the Dini derivatives $\mathscr{D}^+,\mathscr{D}^-,\mathscr{D}_+,\mathscr{D}_-$.

**Theorem 1.** If $(\mathscr{D}f)(x)\geq0$ for all but countably many $x\in(a,b)$, then $f$ is increasing (not necessarily strictly).

**Corollary 2.** If $(\mathscr{D}f)(x)=0$ for all but countably many $x\in(a,b)$, then $f$ is constant.

I followed Berberian's proof of Theorem 1, but I think his proof of Corollary 2 has an error. (On page 228, he applies Theorem 1 to $-f$, which is not justified, since $-f$ may not satisfy conditions (i) and (ii).)
The proof works if $f$ is continuous, since then $-f$ also satisfies conditions (i) and (ii).
My question is: **Is the result of Corollary 2 true? If so, how is it proved?**

---

<sup>[1] *Berberian, Sterling K.*, Fundamentals of real analysis, New York, NY: Springer. xi, 479 p. (1998). [ZBL0914.26001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0914.26001).</sup>

Comment: just fyi, I do not see this in the errata: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnA5S.jpg

Comment: @Calvin Khor Thanks for checking!